# Updating User Information in Firebase in all the Collections

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a sample Twitter App in iOS using Firestore. Currently, I have the following root level collections:

- users
- timelines

In the timelines collection, I have tweets based on the userId and each Tweet also holds a userInfo map, which contains the information about the user who tweeted.

The problem is that if the user updates their name from Steven to Stephan then I can easily update the users collection but I need to go through all the tweets of the user and then update the name. I also need to go through all the replies from that user in other tweets and update the name.

This seems like too much work!

Any ideas how to handle this scenario in Firebase Firestore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any ideas how to handle this scenario in Firebase Firestore.

A classical approach to synchronize your different sets of data (i.e. Documents in different Collections) in a denormalized NoSQL Firestore database is to use [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions).

> If the user updates their name from Steven to Stephan

You can trigger a Cloud Function each time a Firestore document is [updated](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_document_is_updated) or [deleted](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_document_is_deleted). In this Cloud Function you'll query for the documents to update (i.e. query all the docs in the `timelines` collection `where name === "Steven"`) and update them (`name = "Stephan"`) with e.g. a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So if each user has its own timelines collection then I will have to go to each of those timeline for each user and then update the information for the user whose name is changed from Steven to Stephan. Do you think in this case having two root collections "timelines" and "users" will be better? The main issue with that approach is that for each tweet I need to get userInfo and since it is stored in a separate collection it makes it difficult.

Comment: You can think of Twitter app. When someone I follow tweet, that tweet is added to my timeline. If someone likes the tweet then the likes count will go up for me and all the other people who follow that person. Do you think CloudFunction will be a good place to perform an update to the count/retweets etc.

Comment: "Do you think in this case having two root collections "timelines" and "users" will be better?" No, by doing that you would mimick an SQL data model with normalization. in NoSQL world we design our data model based on the queries we are going to execute from the frontend, in such a way we minimize the number of queries. So duplicating the data is a very common approach in the NoSQL world and keeping the different collections in sync via e.g. Cloud Functions is also common.

Comment: I would recommend reading  https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/ and https://firebase.blog/posts/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate your answer.